# How to make urls to view userprofiles like in facebook using laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I am creating a project in Laravel . I want to create a url 
like http://www.mywebsite.com/username
so i can show the user profile based on username

so far i have this code

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'user', 'before' => 'admin'), function() {
        # USer / Individual
        Route::get('/', array('as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@getindex'));
        Route::get('create-user', array('as' => 'create-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@create'));
        Route::get('edit-user/{id}', array('as' => 'edit-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@edit'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::get('delete-user/{id}', array('as' => 'del_user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@destroy'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::get('deactivate/{id}', array('as' => 'user_deactive', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@deactive_user'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::get('active/{id}', array('as' => 'user_active', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@active_user'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));

        Route::post('create-user', array('as' => 'post-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@store'));
        Route::post('update-user/{id}', array('as' => 'update-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@update'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));

       # USer [Individual] Skills
       Route::get('create-skill', array('as' => 'create-user-skill', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@create_skill'));
       Route::get('delete-skill/{id}', array('as' => 'del_skill', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@destroy_skill'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+')); 
       Route::post('create-skill', array('as' => 'create-user-skill', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@store_skill'));

       #send email to user
        Route::get('send-email/{id}', array('as' => 'create-email-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@create_email'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::post('send-email', array('as' => 'send-email-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@send_email'));

    });
```

### I couldnt find any way to create routing for that if i create just a simple route  it disturbs all my other urls like /logout

After Brainstorming here is what i concluded i have to implement it in order to check if this works or not

```
Route::filter('user.item', function($route, $request)
{
    if ($route->parameter('item')->user_id !== Auth::user()->id)
    {
        App::abort(404);
    }
});
```

What ill be doing is applying filter to routes to check from database if that username exists or not if it does exist ill fetch the view for profile and show the profile otherwise run the url as it is .Is it possible that way >?

Answer (score 2):

A route that has a dynamic segment in the first place should be put **after all the other routes** so it only runs when the other routes don't match...

```
Route::get('foo', ...);
Route::get('bar', ...);

Route::get('{user}', ...);
```

Note that there is still a problem because a user can't have the name `create-user` because otherwise he won't see his profile but rather the actual `create-user` route.

That means if you really want to have the profile URL like that you should validate the username and check for reserved words (which are actually your other routes)

Of course the alternative is to just use something like `user/{username}`

Comment: In my eyes that's totally fine. There aren't many sites that allow the the profile URL to be just the username (for a reason). But of course you can do it. The simplest way would be to use only one (or just a few) base URLs for the actual application. For example `app` (so `app/create-user`, `app/logout`) then you'd just have to check that a user can't choose `app` as username and you'd be good to go.

Comment: i have added a filter in my post i am trying now to filter the route before doing any action

Answer (score 0):

You are right that such routing will overload all other routes and nothing works.

It is much easier to create url like http://www.mywebsite.com/u/username

If you want to have route /{username} then you can either make all other urls to be made of 2 or more url segments or make ineffective manual magic in the routing.

In manual routing you can see if the username matches any user and if not then perform the logout for example. You also need to keep in mind that someones username can be logout.

Answer (score 0):

Bind your username "key" (in your route) and create a Route Bind.

```
Route::bind('username',function($value){
   return User::where('username',$value)->first();
});

Route::group(array('prefix' => '{username}', 'before' => 'admin'), function() {
        # USer / Individual
        Route::get('/', array('as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@getindex'));
        Route::get('create-user', array('as' => 'create-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@create'));
        Route::get('edit-user/{id}', array('as' => 'edit-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@edit'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::get('delete-user/{id}', array('as' => 'del_user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@destroy'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::get('deactivate/{id}', array('as' => 'user_deactive', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@deactive_user'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::get('active/{id}', array('as' => 'user_active', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@active_user'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));

        Route::post('create-user', array('as' => 'post-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@store'));
        Route::post('update-user/{id}', array('as' => 'update-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@update'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));

       # USer [Individual] Skills
       Route::get('create-skill', array('as' => 'create-user-skill', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@create_skill'));
       Route::get('delete-skill/{id}', array('as' => 'del_skill', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@destroy_skill'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+')); 
       Route::post('create-skill', array('as' => 'create-user-skill', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@store_skill'));

       #send email to user
        Route::get('send-email/{id}', array('as' => 'create-email-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@create_email'))->where(array('id' => '[0-9]+'));
        Route::post('send-email', array('as' => 'send-email-user', 'uses' => 'Admin\AdminIndividualController@send_email'));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If its ok for you to display URL of the user's profile page like this: `http://website.com/@username` then you can show the user's profile based on his `username` like this:

in `routes.php` file

```
Route::get("@{username}", array(
    "as"   => "users.show",
    "uses" => "UsersController@show",
));
```

in `UsersController.php` file

```
public function show($username)
{
    $user = User::where("username", "=", $username)->first();

    if (is_null($user))
    {
        return App::abort(404);
    }

    return View::make("path/to/view/file")->with("user", $user);
}
```

and you can create links with that URL `http://website.com/@username` like this:

```
<a href="{{ URL::route("users.show", ["@" . $user->username]) }}">{{ $user->username }}</a>
```

this way you don't need to check for reserved words (which are your other routes) unless you already have a route begins with the symbol `@`.